# Unterminated quoted field at end of CSV line. Beginning of lost text

Tags: java, csv, file, parsing, ioexception

I'm trying to parse a CSV file with CSV Reader. the file is very large and I cannot modify it in any way, as I am not the one who created it.

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(nameFile);
   CSVParser csvParser = getCSVParser();
   CSVReader csvReader = getCSVReader(fileReader, csvParser);
   if (csvReader != null) {
      List<String[]> allData = csvReader.readAll();
              ...
   }
```

`csvReader.readALL()` throws the IOException:Unterminated quoted field at end of CSV line. Beginning of lost text:...
How I can solve it?

Comment: Have a look at the offending line and fix it?

Comment: you need to clean and validate your data before parsing.

Comment: @tgdavies I Can't modify the file

Comment: At least look at that line and understand why the field is unterminated. Is it something unusual in the way quotes are escaped?

Comment: there's a field like this " something ; something".

Comment: Which CSV parser are you using, and how is it configured? What's the text of the entire line?

Comment: I'm using com.opencsv.CSVParser and and have not set any configuration. I suppose there are default configurations.

Answer (score 1):

CSV is IMHO the most worst data storage format ever but widely used. And there is defnitly NO standard nor common unterstanding ...

First, analyze your input file and find out what structure is used:
Coma, semicolon, e.t.c as field delimiter. Quoted fields, quoting character, e.t.c.

Second, make sure that there are NO format violations like unquoted filed contains a separation character as literal character or unescaped quoting characters in a field. Especially try to find that line(s) that violate the structure.

Third set the correct options to the CSV parser.

If you have format violations in the file you eigther can try to improve production / export of the file to produce a valid CSV format (if you know the producer and have access to him) or preprocess it with a tool which is able to detect and correct format violations (some kind of a magic crystal ball).